# Extend a class at runtime by accepting base type in constructor?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering to 'grow' a class at runtime. I'm not sure what the correct terminology for what I want to achieve is, but I hope my code sample makes it clear.

```
class foo {
    protected message: string;

    public SetMessage(message: string) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class bar extends foo
{
    constructor(baseClass: foo)
    {
        // Not possible
        this = baseClass as bar;
        alert(this.message);
    }
}

let baseClass = new foo();
baseClass.SetMessage("Hello World");
let extendedClass = new bar(baseClass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear why you're trying to do it, if you want to have the properties of the existing instance in the new one then you can:

```
class bar extends foo {
    constructor(base: foo) {
        super();
        Object.assign(this, base);
    }
}
```